# Trying to click next button while scraping

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scraping program I need to click the next button while scraping and I actually asked a question on here a week or so ago about how to do that that and got some good responses but the code that I got for the answers only works partially.  It will scrape page 1 and page 2 but instead of going on to page 3 it skips to that last page, page 10 and I cannot figure out why.

```
import csv
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from ..items import GameItem
def process_csv(csv_file):
    data = []
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader)
    for fields in reader:
        if fields[0] != "":
            url = fields[0]
        else:
            continue # skip the whole row if the url column is empty
        if fields[1] != "":
            ip = "http://" + fields[1] + ":8050" # adding http and port because this is the needed scheme
        if fields[2] != "":
            useragent = fields[2]
        data.append({"url": url, "ip": ip, "ua": useragent})
    return data
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'splash_spider'  # Name of Spider

    # notice that we don't need to define start_urls
    # just make sure to get all the urls you want to scrape inside start_requests function

    # getting all the url + ip address + useragent pairs then request them
    def start_requests(self):

        # get the file path of the csv file that contains the pairs from the settings.py
        with open(self.settings["PROXY_CSV_FILE"], mode="r") as csv_file:
           # requests is a list of dictionaries like this -> {url: str, ua: str, ip: str}
            requests = process_csv(csv_file)

        for req in requests:
            # no need to create custom middlewares  # just pass useragent using the headers param, and pass proxy using the meta param

            yield SplashRequest(url=req["url"], callback=self.parse, args={"wait": 3},
                    headers={"User-Agent": req["ua"]},
                    splash_url = req["ip"],
                    )

    # Scraping
    def parse(self, response):
        item = GameItem()
        for game in response.css("tr"):
            # Card Name
            yield {
                    'card_name':  game.css("a.card_popup::text").get(),
                    }

           next_page = response.css('table+ div a:nth-child(8)::attr("href")').get()
            if next_page is not None:
                yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

**UPDATE #1**

SplashSpider.py

```
import csv
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from ..items import GameItem

# process the csv file so the url + ip address + useragent pairs are the same as defined in the file # returns a list of dictionaries, example:
# [ {'url': 'http://www.starcitygames.com/catalog/category/Rivals%20of%20Ixalan',
#    'ip': 'http://204.152.114.244:8050',
#    'ua': "Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9320; en-GB) AppleWebKit/534.11"},
#    ...
# ]
def process_csv(csv_file):
    data = []
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader)
    for fields in reader:
        if fields[0] != "":
            url = fields[0]
        else:
            continue # skip the whole row if the url column is empty
        if fields[1] != "":
            ip = "http://" + fields[1] + ":8050" # adding http and port because this is the needed scheme
        if fields[2] != "":
            useragent = fields[2]
        data.append({"url": url, "ip": ip, "ua": useragent})
    return data


class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'splash_spider'  # Name of Spider

    # notice that we don't need to define start_urls
    # just make sure to get all the urls you want to scrape inside start_requests function

    # getting all the url + ip address + useragent pairs then request them
    def start_requests(self):

        # get the file path of the csv file that contains the pairs from the settings.py
        with open(self.settings["PROXY_CSV_FILE"], mode="r") as csv_file:
           # requests is a list of dictionaries like this -> {url: str, ua: str, ip: str}
            requests = process_csv(csv_file)

        for req in requests:
            # no need to create custom middlewares
            # just pass useragent using the headers param, and pass proxy using the meta param

            yield SplashRequest(url=req["url"], callback=self.parse, args={"wait": 3},
                    headers={"User-Agent": req["ua"]},
                    splash_url = req["ip"],
                    )
    # Scraping
    def parse(self, response):
        item = GameItem()
        for game in response.css("tr[class^=deckdbbody]"):
            # Card Name
            item["card_name"] = game.css("a.card_popup::text").extract_first()
            item["stock"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_8::text").extract_first()
            item["price"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_9::text").extract_first()

            yield item
        next_page = response.css('#content > div:last-of-type > a[href]:last-of-type').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page_url, self.parse)
```

**UPDATE #2** *(neither work correctly)*

```
next_page = response.css('#content > div:last-of-type > a[href]:last-of-type').get()
next_page_url = next_page.xpath("@href").get()
if next_page is not None:
    yield response.follow(next_page_url, self.parse)
```

```
next_page = response.css('#content > div:last-of-type > a[href]:last-of-type').get()
if next_page is not None:
    yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is correct code, needed to use xpath instead of css.  Works fine now.

```
next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(., "- Next>>")]/@href').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1):

> `next_page = response.css('table+ div a:nth-child(8)::attr("href")').get()`

You for sure don't want `nth-child(8)`, you want the last `div` and its last `a` that contains an `href` attribute, which is:

```
response.css("#content > div:last-of-type > a[href]:last-of-type')
```

If you wanted to be extra diligent, you'd check the text of the matching `<a>` to ensure it contained the phrase `Next`

Comment: Still not working.  I did what you said but it will not go beyond page 1. Added the updated code to my question.  Can you see what I am still doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using the literal code you posted, then you need [a real editor](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) because you are assigning `next_page` but using `next_page_url`. I would guess the fix is actually between those two, because the `.get()` is going to return the `<a>` not the `href`, so add `next_page_url = next_page.xpath("@href").get()`

Comment: That was just a mistake I made when copying the code, still does not fix problem.  Only doing page 1 still.  Posted new code for next statement.